# How can I make waterfall plots in matplotlib and python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

How do I make a plot like seen here

http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7bk6wu3VW1qfjvexo1_500.gif

The dynamics I don't need. I do need the foreground curves obscuring the background curves.

These are used in pulsar astronomy.

I've experimented with

plt.fill()  and

plt.fill_between()

With no success. Is there an example somewhere in python someone knows about?

Comment: If you're using matplotlib you're going to have a hard time of this. Something like bokeh might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 12):

You can create something like the desired effect by being careful with the z-order of the lines and the fill_under:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='k')

def fG(x, x0, sigma, A):
    """ A simple (un-normalized) Gaussian shape with amplitude A. """
    return A * np.exp(-((x-x0)/sigma)**2)

# Draw ny lines with ng Gaussians each, on an x-axis with nx points
nx, ny, ng = 1000, 20, 4
x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

y = np.zeros((ny, nx))
for iy in range(ny):
    for ig in range(ng):
        # Select the amplitude and position of the Gaussians randomly
        x0 = np.random.random()
        A = np.random.random()*10
        sigma = 0.05
        y[iy,:] += fG(x, x0, sigma, A)
    # Offset each line by this amount: we want the first lines plotted
    # at the top of the chart and to work our way down
    offset = (ny-iy)*5
    # Plot the line and fill under it: increase the z-order each time
    # so that lower lines and their fills are plotted over higher ones
    ax.plot(x,y[iy]+offset, 'w', lw=2, zorder=(iy+1)*2)
    ax.fill_between(x, y[iy]+offset, offset, facecolor='k', lw=0, zorder=(iy+1)*2-1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's beautiful. By the way per [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427458/472876) I had to replace `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='k')` with `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='k')`  . ( `matplotlib.__version__ == '3.3.2'`)