# AttributeError: Unknown property axisbg

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error, data-visualization, attributeerror

Here is a code am trying to run:

```
ax = plt.axes(axisbg='#E6E6E6')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.grid(color='w',linestyle='solid')

for spine in ax.spines.values():
   spine.set_visible(False)

ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.yaxis.tick_left()

ax.tick_params(colors='gray',direction='out')
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
   tick.set_color('gray')
for tick in ax.get_yaxislabels():
   tick.set_color('gray')

ax.hist(x,edgecolor='E6E6E6',color='E6E6E6');
```

And the Error is: AttributeError: Unknown property axisbg

Please help me identify the error.

Comment: That may help you https://github.com/paulbrodersen/matplotlib_venn_wordcloud/issues/3

Comment: Always fun to see a link to your own repo. But yeah: `axisbg` is deprecated in favour of `facecolor`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Replace the below line of code

```
ax = plt.axes(axisbg='#E6E6E6')
```

with

```
ax = plt.axes(facecolor='#E6E6E6')
```

Answer (score 12):

axisbg is deprecated in matplotlib 2.0+
Use facecolor instead.

https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html