# How to solve Unknown property axisbg

Tags: python

I am trying to learn this code [here](https://github.com/convergenceIM/alpha-scientist/blob/master/content/03_Feature_Selection.ipynb)

When running this:

```
corr_matrix = df[selected_features].corr()
correlations_array = np.asarray(corr_matrix)

linkage = hierarchy.linkage(distance.pdist(correlations_array), method='average')

g = sns.clustermap(corr_matrix,row_linkage=linkage,col_linkage=linkage,\
                   row_cluster=True,col_cluster=True,figsize=(6,6),cmap='Greens')
plt.setp(g.ax_heatmap.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=0)
plt.show()

label_order = corr_matrix.iloc[:,g.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind].columns
```

I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: Unknown property axisbg

which is related to:

> self._axes_class.**init**(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)

I tried to read here and there to solve this and failed. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I downloaded the notebook and could run it without problems, which version of matplotlib and seaborn are you using?

Comment: it's on google colab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [axisbg was deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504053/attributeerror-unknown-property-axisbg) in a previous version of matplotlib. The reason you are seeing this error is because Colaboratory is using an older version of seaborn (0.7.1).

To solve this issue add this `!pip install --upgrade seaborn==0.9.0` before the imports. Make sure you [restart your runtime after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226306/google-colab-not-updating-package).

Comment: thanks, so every time i will need to restart my runtime after the install?

Comment: I'd assume so. I couldn't find any docs from Colab that tells how the dependencies are managed.